# Changing Windows Boot Manager config from a Linux environment?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, arch-linux

My problem stems from an attempt to set up Windows 8.1 and Arch-Linux dual boot from a single disk. After creating a partition for Linux and going through the installation using an arch iso image burned to a DVD, I returned to windows. Using a program called EasyBCD, I set up an option to be able to boot Linux as well as windows (or so I thought).

When I rebooted, both options were there, but the Linux option was ineffective. I went back into EasyBCD and removed the Linux option - leaving only windows (I planned to install a Linux boot manager instead because EasyBCD seemed a bit iffy). But when I rebooted again - not the Linux option, but the windows option was gone! This obviously raises the question 'did you perhaps change the option to boot windows by mistake? - to which the answer is definitely no, unless EasyBCD did something behind the scenes I wasn't aware of.

So I was left unable to boot either OS from my HD. I went back into the arch DVD environment and installed a Linux boot loader called gummiboot. I added gummiboot's EFI executable to my UEFI boot menu using the Linux tool efibootmgr. Since then I am able to boot arch from the HD, but the problem with Windows Boot Manager remains in that it gives me a broken option to boot Linux, but no option to boot windows.

My question is, can I edit or reset the windows boot manager config so it does allow me to boot windows 8.1? I do have access to a UEFI shell as well as a DOS environment on a disc that came with my motherboard, however no windows disc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try repairing it using the following software

http://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Booting your computer with that software allows you to access your hardrive within its own built in mini XP OS so you can delete the require parts or files if needed. You can also use the tool to recover any data before you reformat the drive if you need to do that.

Comment: Ok - have you used this software and would you vouch for it?

Comment: I use it all the time as part of my job, very good piece of software, you will see all the tools it includes when you boot into it along with the one i mentioned